# Graphics card with HDMI (including sound)?

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi

I have an HTPC with an onboard NVidia 630a chipset that I've been using for 1080p video and Skype. Unfortunately, nVidia screwed up their drivers, and I lost sound over HDMI a while back. For reasons I won't go into, rolling back the chipset drivers isn't working, so the simplest solution seems to be to disable the 630a chipset and add a graphics card with HDMI.

I'm looking for suggestions for a PCI-E card that does HDMI, including sound-over-HDMI. I don't do any gaming, so 1080p and Skype are probably the heaviest demand I'll place on the card. The computer is a small-form-factor, so I need a single-slot card. What would you recommend? Thanks.

Comment: Shopping Recommendations are off-topic for SU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A low end ATI card will do what you want. Anything 4000 series or later will have the oopmh to decode 1080p and do audio via HDMI. Just make sure it has a port onboard or an adapter in the box, they're difficult to find online sometimes and have varied between chipsets.